# Reference on separability of $c_0(X)$, where $X$ is a separable Banch space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a separable Banach space.
By $c_0(X)$ I mean the space $\{(x_n)_n\subset X:\, \|x_n\|\to0\}$.
I think it os well known that $c_0(X)$ is  a separable Banach space endowed with the norm $$\|(x_n)_n\|_\infty:=\sup_n\|x_n\|.$$
I need a reference on that, but i'm not able to find it.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The proof is quite simple. Let $S$ be a countable dense set in $X$ and show that the set of all sequences of the form $(c_1,c_2,...,c_N,0,0...)$ where $N \geq 1$ and each $c_i \in S$ is a countable dense set.

Comment: Thenks, I already know how to prove it. I am only looking for a reference on that, if exists.

Comment: Just for fun: one way to mention it without any detailed proof could be the representation $c_0(X) = c_0 \hat \otimes_\varepsilon X$ (cf e.g., Ryans's "Introduction to tensor products...", Example 3.3). Of course, I could not immediately find a direct reference to the easy fact that separability is kept under tensor products, but maybe you have better luck finding this.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect most introductory Banach space books will provide this as either an example or an exercise; as the comments say this is quite straightforward to prove.  However, a nice reference is Fabian, Habala, Hajek, Montesinos and Zizler; Banach Space Theory, page $22$, proposition $1.42$.

Comment: I also suspect so, but I have benn asked for a reference and do not find.